# Building dynamic poll with jquery, php and html

Tags: php, jquery, html

Okey, this is what I've got.

`<?php
$options[1] = 'jQuery';
$options[2] = 'Ext JS';
$options[3] = 'Dojo';
$options[4] = 'Prototype';
$options[5] = 'YUI';
$options[6] = 'mootools';`

That is my array, but I'd like to make it a bit more dynamic so that the array is built according to input id, so he won't have to change the php-code whenever he want's another poll. How would I import those input id's and push them into an array?

Answer (score 0):

To the extent I can understand your question, you could use JSON to pass the data from the client to the server like this:

**JAVASCRIPT** (using jQuery):

```
var arr = [];
arr.push("option1");
arr.push("option2"); // and so on..

//Use AJAX to send the data across ..
$.ajax({
        url: 'poll.php?jsondata=' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(arr)),
        success: function(data) {
            // response..
        }
    });
});
```

I think that PHP script will put those options into a database or something for using it later on.

Now, in **PHP**(poll.php):

```
<?php
    $options = json_decode($_GET['jsondata']);
    //...
?>
```

Comment: Thing is, I'd like the jquery or php to use perhaps a class and then dynamically create an array with perhaps the div id's or something like that. So one array defined by the class ".radios" and then push each div-id into that array.